# Central limit theorem for exponential random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

Consider the following problem:

Suppose that $(e_n)_n$ are independent exponentially distributed random variable with $E[e_n]=\mu_n.$ If $$\lim_n\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{\mu_k}{\sum_{r=1}^n\mu_r}=0.$$
then $$\sum_{k=1}^n(e_k-\mu_k)/\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\mu^2_k} \implies N(0;1).$$

It's obvious that we need to prove Lindeberg condition, so in order to prove it, we need the assumption $\lim_n\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{\mu_k}{\sum_{r=1}^n\mu^2_r}=0$ and not the above.

Is it possible the there is a typo in this exercise? Is there any counterexample to disprove it?

Note that this question was asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362432/clt-for-independent-but-non-identically-distributed-exponential-variables), but it's not confirmed.

Comment: If $M_n=\left ( \sum_{k=1}^n \mu_k^2 \right )^{1/2}$, I find that to finish the last step of validating the Lindeberg condition, you should have $\frac{M_n}{\mu_k}$ growing fast enough that $\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-M_n/\mu_k} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. For example a bound like $\frac{M_n}{\mu_k} \geq \log(n)^p$ for $p>1$ is sufficient for this behavior, as is $\frac{M_n}{\mu_k} \geq n^\delta$ for any $\delta>0$.

Comment: (Cont.) Can you get that from this given condition? It seems a little bit delicate  because $M_n$ does not grow as fast as $\sum_{k=1}^n \mu_k$ does (the latter is between $1$ and $\sqrt{n}$ times larger).

Comment: you mean further assumption are needed?

Comment: I'm not sure, you might be able to massage the given condition into what I said.

Comment: @Kurt.W.X Pls consider the case: $\mu_n=1/n, n\ge 1$.

Comment: I actually am not so sure that just $\frac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \mu_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n \mu_k^2} \to 0$ is sufficient. The natural point of comparison has the square root already there in the denominator. And even with the square root there I think you might need a *tiny* bit of speed, beyond just going to zero.

Comment: There should be a square root the following holds:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961865/central-limit-theorem-for-weighted-random-variable, the above is a particular case

Comment: We can see that $\frac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}\mu_k}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n}\mu_k^2}$ implies that $\sum_{k=1}^n \mu_k ^2 \to +\infty,\mu_n=o(\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\mu_k^2})$ since $\mu_1/\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \mu_k^2} \leq \max_{1 \leq k \leq n}\mu_k/\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \mu_k^2}$

Comment: I guess the point is that if $\mu_k \to 0$ and $M_n \to \infty$ then the tail of the sum doesn't hurt anything, and if $\mu_k \to \infty$ then only the tail can hurt anything and in this case the given condition "saves the day". Something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $ \{X_n,n\ge 1\}$ are exponentially distributed random variables with $ \mathsf{E}[X_n]=\mu_n $. Then
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\max\limits_{1\le i\le n}\mu_i}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \mu_j}=0 \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
is not sufficient for the following CLT
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu_i)}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\mu_j^2}}
 \Rightarrow N(0,1). \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
For example, $\mu_n=\frac1n$. In this case,
\begin{equation*}
 \max\limits_{1\le i\le n}\mu_i=1 , \qquad
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu_j=\infty,
\end{equation*}
hence (1) holds.

On the other hand, since $ \mathsf{Var}[X_n]=\mu_n^2=\frac1{n^2} $,
\begin{equation*}
 c^2=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mathsf{Var}[X_j]=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{j^2}\Big(=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\Big)<\infty.
\end{equation*}
Using Kolmogorov Convergence Criterion(Please refer to the book
"S. I. Resnick, *A Probability Path*, Birkhäuser Boston, 2005." Th.7.3.3, p212.
) to get both
\begin{equation*}
 S_1=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(X_j-\mu_j),\quad  S_2=\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}(X_j-\mu_j) 
\end{equation*}
converge almost surely.
Mean while $(X_1-\mu_1)$, $S_2  $ are independent mutually,  hence $ S_1=(X_1-\mu_1)+S_2 $
couldn't be Gaussian distributed and
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu_i)}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\mu_j^2}}
 =\frac{S_1}{c}\stackrel{d}{\ne}N(0,1).
\end{equation*}
This means that (1) is not sufficient for (2)

Comment: Nice...in this case the sum of $\mu^2$ doesn't even grow at all so there is just no way.